# Can't echo Ajax variable pass

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm passing 2 variables with ajax to the same .php file. I see them in the console.log but I can't seem to echo them. I already tried several things I found in other questions but it doesn't seem to work. What do I need to add/change?

My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function (e, data) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "../wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/fields/test.php",
            data : {
                minValue : data.values.min,
                maxValue : data.values.max
            },
            cache : true,
            async : false,
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function (xhr) {
                alert('fail')
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and the php part:

```
<?php if ( $_POST ) {
    echo $_POST['minValue'];
 }

?>
```

Btw: it only passes the first value (minValue) and not the other one. How to pass them both? Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: what do you get for `alert('data')`

Comment: I need the form code from where you are getting the values.

Comment: first try  to get what is going on page try beforeSend: function(){console.log(data)}, to check what in coming in data

Comment: is `maxValue : data.values.max` actually getting the values??

Comment: @Neeraj Singh I did this indeed, and it is showing me two values. 

`$("#values").text( data.values.min + " tot " + data.values.max + " Studiepunten");`

Comment: @LarsKerff: share your html code here

Comment: can i get your form so that i can try it on my local machine?

Comment: @Neeraj Singh I'm testing several things right now, it seems to work when I post to another url. Maybe I can send it back by a session.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by printing both values?

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo $_POST['minValue'];
    echo $_POST['maxValue'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I can see in the log that there's only one value passing. So that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see your request details in the Debug panels like Firebug in FF or (I don't know how it called) in Chromium-based browsers?
Are there all the passed data?
If no then the error in JS.

Also print out the whole POST data on server side to see the POST content.

Answer (score 0):

To pass more values try something like this on php side:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2
));
```